# ReportLab: How to start writing from the upper left point of the paragraph, because by default it is from the lower left point

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, paragraph

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4 
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Dejavu', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf'


packet_1 = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet_1, pagesize=A4)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["BodyText"]


my_style = ParagraphStyle(name ='My style',
                          fontName='Dejavu',
                          fontSize=12,
                          alignment=TA_LEFT,
                          borderWidth = 1,
                          borderColor = 'black'
                          )

p3 = Paragraph('''abdc''', my_style)
p3.wrapOn(can, 500, 100)
p3.drawOn(can, 10, 300)
```

Regardless of the paragraph height, the text starts at the bottom.
How to make it start from the top?

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb` the library used in this answer.

`borb` is a pure Python PDF library that provides both a low-level (you decide at which exact coordinates content goes) and a high-level (`borb` takes care of the layout for you) model.

You can check out the examples, there's a whole section on `Paragraph` alignment. You can find that [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#243-using-alignment-on-paragraph-objects).

In the examples, a `Paragraph` is added at exact coordinates, and laid out with various `Alignment` parameters.

I'll copy the relevant example here for completeness:

```py
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.layout_element import Alignment
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.square_annotation import SquareAnnotation
from borb.pdf.canvas.color.color import HexColor

from decimal import Decimal


def main():
    # create Document
    doc: Document = Document()

    # create Page
    page: Page = Page()

    # add Page to Document
    doc.append_page(page)

    # define layout rectangle
    # fmt: off
    r: Rectangle = Rectangle(
        Decimal(59),                # x: 0 + page_margin
        Decimal(848 - 84 - 100),    # y: page_height - page_margin - height_of_textbox
        Decimal(595 - 59 * 2),      # width: page_width - 2 * page_margin
        Decimal(100),               # height
    )
    # fmt: on

    # this is a quick hack to easily get a rectangle on the page
    # which can be very useful for debugging
    page.append_annotation(SquareAnnotation(r, stroke_color=HexColor("#ff0000")))

    # the next line of code uses absolute positioning
    Paragraph("Hello World!", vertical_alignment=Alignment.TOP).layout(page, r)

    # store
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should produce the following PDF:

[image]

I added a red rectangle around the Paragraph to illustrate that the content is in fact laid out with `vertical_alignment` set to `Alignment.TOP`.

Comment: I started a project in ReportLab, have already written a lot of code and am trying to come up with something using this library.

Answer (score 1):

add `bottomup=0` exp:

```
...
can = canvas.Canvas(packet_1, pagesize=A4, bottomup=0)
...
```